# How to prove a set of lines is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove if the following set is bounded $$S=\bigcup_{a\in(0,1)} M_{a},$$ where
$$M_{a}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: ax+(1-a)y=b, x>0, y>0, b \text{ is a fixed positive real number}\}.$$
I think this set is bounded since all lines in the set are bounded by the vertical line $x = b$ and the horizontal line $y=b$. However, I am not sure how to prove it formally?
Thanks!

**Edited: the expression set is reformed and my attempt for this is as follows**
$$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} M_a = {(x,y)}\in \mathbb{R}^2: y=b, x\in (0,\infty)$$
and
$$\lim_{a \rightarrow 1} M_a = {(x,y)}\in \mathbb{R}^2: x=b, y\in (0,\infty).$$
Does this implies that $S$ is bounded?

Comment: What is the metric you are using for the set of lines? Remember, the concept of "bounded" only exists in a **metric space**. Before you ask yourself whether a set is bounded, you **must** define what metric space you are looking that set in. A set, on its own, is neither bounded nor unbounded, and it can, in fact, be either, depending on the metric.

Comment: $ (nb,\frac  1n) , a=\frac  1n,y=0 $ shows that this set is not bounded.

Comment: If you are fixing $a$ and $b$ then $0<x \leq b/a$ and $0 <y <b/(1-a)$.

Comment: @5xum I think the metric space here can be defined as $d: \mathcal{R} \times \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}_{+} \times \mathcal{R}_{+}$.

Comment: @Xuan It cannot. The set $S$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. Elements of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ are **pairs** of real numbers. Members of $S$ are **subsets** of real numbers.

Comment: @5xum Is the members of $S$ lines passing through the point $(b/a, b/(1-a))$? If that's the case, should they be pairs of real numbers?

Comment: @Xuan I don't understand your question.

Comment: @5xum What I was trying to describe above is a set of lines passing through the point $(b/a,b/(1−a))$ on the $x-y$ plane, where their slopes are between $0$ and $1$ (do not include $0$ and $1$). So I am wondering if we can say that this set is bounded by the line $x=b/a$ and the line $y=b/(1-a)$?

Comment: @Xuan I understand what you are describing, and my point stands: before saying a set is bounded or not, you **must** describe what metric space you are looking at. You did not yet define a metric space. Either define a metric space or redefine $S$ to be in a known metric space (such as $\mathbb R^2$) if you want your question to make sense.

Comment: @5xum In this case, $S$ is in the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Will this make more sense?

Comment: @Xuan $S$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. So no, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @5xum So, the set should be described as follows: $S={a \in (0,1): {(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: ax+(1-a)y=b, x,y>0}}$.

Comment: @Xuan If $b$ fixed? Or should there be a quantifier to bound it?

Comment: @5xum Yes, $b$ is a fixed positive real number.

Comment: @Xuan Then $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, according to your definition?

Comment: @5xum Then, that doesn't align with what I was thinking. I think a more straightforward way to describe $S$ is that $S==\bigcup_{a \in (0,1)M_{a}},$ where $M_{a} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: ax+(1-a)y=b, x,y>0 and b is a positive real number \}$

Comment: @Xuan Ah, that makes sense now. In this case, no, $S$ is not bounded. I have added a full answer explaining why below.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition of $S$, which is $$S=\cup_{a\in(0,1)} \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R_+^2| ax+(1-a)y = b\},$$

the set $S$ is **not** bounded.

For an intuitive idea, think of it this way. For any $M>0$, let's try to find a point $(x, y)$ such that $\|(x,y)\|$ is at least $M$. One way to achieve this is to have $x$ be at least $M$. Well, if $x$ is $M$, then $$ax+(1-a)y = aM + (1-a)y.$$

So we know that $aM$, plus something **positive**, must equal $b$. We can achieve this by making $aM$ smaller than $b$. Can we do that? **YES**. If $a$ is small enough (and we still have the freedom to pick $a$), then $aM$ can become arbitrarily small, and we will be able to then pick a $y$ such that the total sum will be $b$. In particular, we can choose $a$ such that $aM = \frac b2$, which means that $(1-a)y$ must also be $\frac b2$ - this is again something we *can* achieve by setting $y=\frac{b}{2(1-a)}$.

---

To put this all together, you can show that $S$ is not bounded. In particular, for any $M>b$, the point

$$\left(M, \frac{bM}{2M-b}\right)$$ is an element of the set. This is because, for $a=\frac{b}{2M}$, the point $\left(M, \frac{bM}{2M-b}\right)$ is an element of the set $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R_+^2| ax+(1-a)y = b\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have updated my attempt above. If we are considering $S$ as the combination of all $M_a$, of which are lines in the x-y plane, shouldn't the boundary of this set to be a line instead of a point?

Comment: @Xuan A "boundary" has little to do with a set being "bounded". These are two mathematical expressions that both have strict definitions. Also, be careful not to confuse the set $\bigcup_{a\in(0,1)} M_a$ with the set $\{M_a|a\in(0,1)\}$. Again, these are two completely different sets. One is a set of points in the plane, while another is a set of *lines*.

Comment: @Xuan Also, be **very** careful when writing expressions like $$\lim_{a\to 1} M_a.$$ This expression is, again, **meaningless**. A **limit** is something that is defined for **sequences of real numbers** and for **real valued functions**. In other words, if $f(a)$ is a function mapping to $\mathbb R$, then it makes sense to talk about $\lim_{a\to 0} f(a)$. But you cannot just throw around the term "limit" willy nilly.

Comment: @Xuan Which leads me to my general advice, and that is to **slow down**. You are letting your ideas run a little rampant here, and it leads to you writing down expressions which are sloppy and incorrect. That's not the mathematical way. Try to be precise both when asking a question and when answering it. Use only terms that are well defined, and do not use them too broadly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Very appreciated! Just to be sure, $\bigcup_{a \in (0,1)} M_a$ is a set of lines, right?

Comment: @Xuan No. It's a set of points. $M_a$ is a set of points for each $a$. The union of several sets of points is still a set of points.

Comment: I think I got that. Then, as you said above $\{M_a|a \in (0,1)\}$ is a set of lines for all $a \in (0,1)$, right?

Comment: @Xuan Yes. That one is a set of lines. But for the set of lines, it's hard to speak about bounds because it is not in a metric space.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: The set $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}: ax+(1-a)y=b, x>0, y>0\}: 0<a<1\}$ is unbounded if $b>0$ and empty otherwise.

Proof:
$ax+(1-a)y$ is positive. So if $b\leq 0$, then we can't find appropriate $(x,y)$. Therefore x is empty.

For the next case, if $b>0$, WLOG, let's assume b is some number greater than 1. Specifically, let's take $b=2$.(If not, $(x,y)$ can be appropriately scaled such that this is true).

Pick some large $N$ that you want to bound with. Then $S\subset[0,N]\times[0,N]$
Now given any such $N$, one can find some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}>N$. Set $a=\epsilon$. We then set y to be some small quantity, say $\epsilon$, such that $b-(1-\epsilon)y>1$
Then for such points $(x,y)$ in S:
\begin{align*}
a x+(1-a)y&=b\\
a x &=b-(1-a)y\\
\epsilon x &>1\\
x &>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\\
x &>N\\
\end{align*}

Thus we found such $(x,y) \in S$ that is not bound by $[0,N]\times[0,N]$, and therefore we have a contradiction to the bound on $S$. Therefore $S$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But since each element in $S$ is a line, should the boundary be a line as well?

Comment: while you have formulated the set thinking of lines, the final set $S$ is no more a line. It's some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, once you fix a b, the set of lines that you speak about are the set of tangents to the bounding curve (looks like a hyperbola with x and y axis as asymptotes. Is it a hyperbola? requires proof). Then S is the set of points between this curve and the x and y axes.